# Error at Watin.Core.Comparer StringComparer class

Tags: watin, argumentnullexception, stringcomparer

I am using Watin system in my program.

I get the following error:

> **ArgumentNullException at Watin.Core.Comparer**
>   **StringComparer(string comparisonValue, bool ignoreCase)**
>   **Error : Value Cannot be Null(comparisonValue)**

But I have no idea that who and when stringcomparer is called,
also I don't know how to debug it.

Here is some of my code.

```
using (IE browser = new IE(url))  
            {  
                Trace.TraceInformation("success to create IE instance.");

                int waitSecond = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30).Seconds;
                browser.WaitForComplete(waitSecond);
                .........
                .........
            }
       )
```

Add some ErrorTrace

```
at WatiN.Core.Comparers.StringComparer..ctor(String comparisonValue, Boolean ignoreCase)
at WitiN.core.DialogHandlers.DialogWatcher.HasDialogSameProcessNameAsBrowserWindow(Window window)
at WatiN.Core.DialogHandlers.DialogWatcher.HandleWindow(Window window)
at WatiN.Core.DialogHandlers.DialogWatcher.Start()
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart_Context(ojbect state)
at System.Threading.ExecutionContext.Runinternal(exceutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.ExecutinoContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state, Boolean preserveSyncCtx)
at System.Threading.ExecutinoContext.Run(ExecutionContext executionContext, ContextCallback callback, Object state)
at System.Threading.ThreadHelper.ThreadStart()
```

Comment: Have you confirmed with a debugger that `url` is non-null?

Comment: Please post the complete error and traceback.

Comment: @BACON yes, I checked. url value is not null.

Comment: @BurhanKhalid I added error and traceback.

Answer (score 0):

This code works as expected (no exceptions thrown):

```
        using (IE browser = new IE("http://www.google.com"))
        {
            //Trace.TraceInformation("success to create IE instance.");

            int waitSecond = TimeSpan.FromSeconds(30).Seconds;
            browser.WaitForComplete(waitSecond);
        }
```

Make sure you are using the latest sources for WatiN and you don't have any other code executing at that time (the exception you are getting if for a DialogWatcher, nothing to do with the code you posted).

Not sure why you've used the `.WaitForComplete` method like that but that method is called by default internally for each method you run that interacts with a web page. If you want to specify a generic wait time for loading web pages you should use settings for the WatiN object like this:

```
        Settings.WaitForCompleteTimeOut = 30;
        using (IE browser = new IE("http://www.google.com"))
        {
            //Trace.TraceInformation("success to create IE instance.");
            browser.WaitForComplete();
        }
```